# Converting server time to localtime momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have an API which gives me the following info

**Backend API:**

/api/time

```
{
  "timeZoneOffset": -18000000, (milli sec)
  "serverTimeUTC": 1485332569157,
  "serverTime": "Wed Jan 25 03:22:49 EST 2017",
  "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time"
}
```

I have another API through which I get time from reports

API: /reports/

```
{
"reportTime": "01/24/2017 12:06 AM"
}
```

How can I display the reportTime in local system time? (browser time?)

I've tried:

```
browserTime = moment(reportTime).utcOffset(moment().utcOffset()).format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A');
```

(I'm currently in PST so offset is -480)

I'm not able to get this working. Please help.

Comment: Which is the relation between the two APIs? What does the first object stand for?

Comment: The first API is the API coming from backend. Second API is report API also coming from backend which has got reportTime. I want to write momentJS code

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `reportTime` to local time by doing:

```
var localTime  = moment.utc(reportTime).toDate();
    localTime = moment(localTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

More convinient way use http://momentjs.com/timezone/. It enables conversion from EST to PST

Comment: but reportTime is NOT in UTC. It's in EST and the browser is in PST.

Comment: But where does it take offset into consideration. This is what i get..`https://puu.sh/tBCHU/120b4fa50d.png` but ideally this time is in EST i.e 3PM (in the screenshot) and I should get 12PM (I'm in PST) which is 3 hours behind.